# Trouble installing data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having trouble installing the data.table package (running OS X Yosemite)

Executing `install.packages("data.table")` seems to give me no issues, but when I run `library(data.table)` I get the following error:

> Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In gzfile(file, "rb") :
>     cannot open compressed file '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/plyr/data/Rdata.rdx', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘data.table’

Comment: Do you have package `plyr` installed?

Comment: Did you try `install.packages("data.table", dependencies=TRUE)`? This is a bit of a puzzle but  I was surprised that data.table "suggested" plyr. The DESCRIPTION file says: `Depends: R (>= 2.14.0)
Imports: methods, chron
Suggests: ggplot2 (>= 0.9.0), plyr, reshape, reshape2, testthat (>=
        0.4), hexbin, fastmatch, nlme, xts, bit64, gdata,
        GenomicRanges, caret, knitr, RCurl, zoo`

Comment: Thanks @Pascal and @BondedDust , I just needed to install `plyr` and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @BondedDust, `suggests` field contains all packages that we use in tests (for the most part). [Here's one test for `plyr`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/inst/tests/tests.Rraw#L889).

Comment: @Jama22 could you please answer the Q yourself and accept it? Thanks. (alternatively I can flag to delete the Q).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to install plyr and it worked perfectly!